# Trigger a bash script at startup to execute periodically

Tags: linux, bash

I have made a bash script, let's call it script.sh, which has the next sctructure:

`#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    do_something()
    sleep 1800 #seconds
done`

I want the script to run as a task at startup although there is no user connected to the system. I thought that I could use 'nohup script.sh' but I don't know if I can use it at startup without any user connected. Have anybody some idea?

Comment: Look into [tag:cron].

Comment: You can do a little search about `/etc/rc.local` or you better yet  you can make it a daemon

Comment: Like Tiago said, you could benefit from /etc/rc.local (Example: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1709280)

Answer (score 1):

Look into using `/etc/cron.hourly/` for an hourly script. It will run hourly at some interval past the hour. On RHEL, this is defined in `/etc/cron.d/0hourly` as 1 minute past the hour.

You could then extend this framework for half-hour intervals (1800s = 30 minutes), e.g., in `/etc/cron.d/1_halfhourly`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
00,30 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.halfhourly
```

And put your script, or symlink it, in `/etc/cron.halfhourly`.

Naturally, this could be extended right down to one minute intervals, e.g., in `/etc/cron.d/2perminute`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
* * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.perminute
```

This would run every script under `/etc/cron.perminute` each minute.